# Upload and store mulltiple files then insert to html

Tags: php

I want to allow users to upload their pictures in order to make a lightbox.
So for that, I need to store multiple images in one column into database and append these ones in `HTML`.

I think I have to assign a unique key to each image but I've no idea how to do that.

The `php script` returns the following error :

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\yaute_love\content\account.php:190 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\yaute_love\content\account.php(190): PDOStatement->fetchAll(2) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\yaute_love\index.php(38): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\yaute_love\content\account.php on line 190

Here's the database :

[image]

**HTML :**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="account" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
        <div class="uk-margin-small" uk-form-custom="target: true">
            <input id="img" type="file" name="image-user[]" value="" multiple>
            <input class="uk-input uk-form-width-medium" type="text" placeholder="Select photos" disabled>
        </div>
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary" type="submit" name="mosaic-form">upload</button>
</form>
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    $req_id = $sql_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $req_id->bindValue(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
    $req_id->execute();
    $user = $req_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (isset($_POST['mosaic-form'])) {
        $files = $_FILES;
        $count = count($_FILES['image-user']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $_FILES['image-user']['name']= $files['image-user']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['image-user']['type']= $files['image-user']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['image-user']['tmp_name']= $files['image-user']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['image-user']['error']= $files['image-user']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['image-user']['size']= $files['image-user']['size'][$i];
        };
        $image_uploaded = $_FILES['image-user'];
        if (is_uploaded_file($image_uploaded['tmp_name'])) {
            $valid_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            $valid_type = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
            $image_uploadedName = basename($image_uploaded['name']);
            $name = strtolower(explode('.', $image_uploadedName)[0]);
            $ext = strtolower(explode('.', $image_uploadedName)[1]);
            if (in_array($ext, $valid_ext)) {
                if (in_array($image_uploaded['type'], $valid_type)) {
                    $error = array('type' => 'success');
                    if (in_array('image/jpg', $valid_type) || in_array('image/jpeg', $valid_type)) {
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_uploaded['tmp_name']);
                    }
                    else if (in_array('image/png', $valid_type)) {
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_uploaded['tmp_name']);
                    }
                    $imgSize = getimagesize($image_uploaded['tmp_name']);
                    $resizeSizeImg = 800;
                    if ($imgSize[0] > $imgSize[1]) {
                        $thumbnailWidth = $resizeSizeImg;
                        $thumbnailHeight = round($imgSize[1] / $imgSize[0] * $resizeSizeImg);
                    } else {
                        $thumbnailWidth = round($imgSize[0] / $imgSize[1] * $resizeSizeImg);
                        $thumbnailHeight = $resizeSizeImg;
                    }
                    $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnailWidth, $thumbnailHeight);
                    imagealphablending($thumbnail, false);
                    imagesavealpha($thumbnail, true);
                    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnailWidth, $thumbnailHeight, $imgSize[0],$imgSize[1]);
                    if (in_array('image/jpg', $valid_type) || in_array('image/jpeg', $valid_type)) {
                        imagejpeg($thumbnail, 'public/img/upload/'.$name.'.'.$ext);
                        $name_image = $name.'.'.$ext;
                        $image_user = $sql_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO images (name, users_id) VALUES (:name, :users_id)');
                        $image_user->bindValue(':users_id', $user['id']);
                        $image_user->bindValue(':name', $name_image);
                        $image_user->execute();
                        $img = $image_user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($img as $val) {
                            echo '
                                <a href="'.$val['name'].'">
                                    <img src="public/img/upload/'.$val['name'].'" alt="user image" />
                                </a>
                            ';
                        };
                        header('Location: account');
                    }
                    elseif (in_array('image/png', $valid_type)) {
                        imagepng($thumbnail, 'public/img/upload/'.$name.'.'.$ext);
                        $name_image = $name.'.'.$ext;
                        $image_user = $sql_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO images (name, users_id) VALUES (:name, :users_id)');
                        $image_user->bindValue(':users_id', $user['id']);
                        $image_user->bindValue(':name', $name_image);
                        $image_user->execute();
                        $img = $image_user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($img as $val) {
                            echo '
                                <a href="'.$val['name'].'">
                                    <img src="public/img/upload/'.$val['name'].'" alt="user image" />
                                </a>
                            ';
                        };
                        header('Location: account');
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="uk-text-danger">Not an image !</p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<p class="uk-text-danger">Not an image !</p>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Please, note that I'm php newbie, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it.

**PHP :**

```
<?
    function reArrangeFiles($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $key => $all) {
            foreach($all as $i => $val) {
                $new[$i][$key] = $val;
            };
        };
        return $new;
    };
    if (isset($_POST['mosaic-form'])) {
        $file_ary = reArrangeFiles($_FILES['image-user']);
        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
                $valid_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
                $valid_type = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');
                $image_uploadedName = basename($file['name']);
                $name = strtolower(explode('.', $image_uploadedName)[0]);
                $ext = strtolower(explode('.', $image_uploadedName)[1]);
                if (in_array($ext, $valid_ext)) {
                    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_type)) {
                        if (in_array('image/jpg', $valid_type) || in_array('image/jpeg', $valid_type)) {
                            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
                        }
                        else if (in_array('image/png', $valid_type)) {
                            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
                        }
                        $imgSize = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
                        $resizeSizeImg = 800;
                        if ($imgSize[0] > $imgSize[1]) {
                            $thumbnailWidth = $resizeSizeImg;
                            $thumbnailHeight = round($imgSize[1] / $imgSize[0] * $resizeSizeImg);
                        } else {
                            $thumbnailWidth = round($imgSize[0] / $imgSize[1] * $resizeSizeImg);
                            $thumbnailHeight = $resizeSizeImg;
                        }
                        $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnailWidth, $thumbnailHeight);
                        imagealphablending($thumbnail, false);
                        imagesavealpha($thumbnail, true);
                        imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnailWidth, $thumbnailHeight, $imgSize[0],$imgSize[1]);
                        if (in_array('image/jpg', $valid_type) || in_array('image/jpeg', $valid_type)) {
                            imagejpeg($thumbnail, 'public/img/upload/'.$name.'.'.$ext);
                            $name_image = $name.'.'.$ext;
                            $image_user = $sql_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO images (name, users_id) VALUES (:name, :users_id)');
                            $image_user->bindValue(':users_id', $user['id']);
                            $image_user->bindValue(':name', $name_image);
                            $image_user->execute();
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="uk-text-danger">Ce n\'est pas une image !</p>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="uk-text-danger">Ce n\'est pas une image !</p>';
                }
            }
        };
    }
    $req_img = $sql_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM images WHERE users_id = :users_id');
    $req_img->bindValue(':users_id', $user['id']);
    $req_img->execute();
    $img = $req_img->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($img) {
        foreach ($img as $val) { ?>
            <a href="public/img/upload/<? echo $val['name']; ?>">
                <img src="public/img/upload/<? echo $val['name']; ?>" alt="user image" />
            </a>
    <?  };
    } else {
        echo '<p class="uk-padding uk-padding-small uk-width-1-1">Vous n\'avez pas encore ajouté de photos.</p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters this code looks not right...

```
$files = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['image-user']['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $_FILES['image-user']['name']= $files['image-user']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['image-user']['type']= $files['image-user']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['image-user']['tmp_name']= $files['image-user']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['image-user']['error']= $files['image-user']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['image-user']['size']= $files['image-user']['size'][$i];
};
```

You may have meant it to look like this...

```
$files = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['image-user']['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $files['image-user']['name'][$i]= $_FILES['image-user']['name'];
    $files['image-user']['type'][$i]= $_FILES['image-user']['type'];
    $files['image-user']['tmp_name'][$i]= $_FILES['image-user']['tmp_name'];
    $files['image-user']['error'][$i]= $_FILES['image-user']['error'];
    $files['image-user']['size'][$i]= $_FILES['image-user']['size'];
};
```

which might make some sense,, but its very strange that $files is not used anywhere after that loop!

There may be several other problems - especially if you are new to PHP and modifying code from somewhere else.